# How to crop an image taking base a rectangle in android?

Tags: android

I'm implementing a custom camera, in the layout I have a rectangle inside the layout, where the user have to put his card, so after take the photo i need crop the picture, taking the reference the rectangle.

Any suggestion of how to do this?

[image]

Comment: could you post the code that you've got so far please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you can use a library that do this on your behalf.
If you are not fully satisfied and need to understand how it works the process you can read the API. I do not know exact if you mean the selection have to be a rectangle of you are referring to the rectangle of your customer view where the card should fit, in the first case the [library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) from Arthurhub should be enough

if you want to implement from scratch, I guess you need to use Matrix 
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html)

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: Thanks, at the end I used math for determinate the new size of the picture, I use a cross-multiplication to get the relative size.

Comment: @JavierOlan can you please post the code how you have achieved this programmatically. I need the same thing to be done and its working for small devices but for high resolution devices its not working

Comment: Yes sure, here is the method https://gist.github.com/javikin/1de5fc5196abef9f52cdff4f40e4ed33, and here you can find the layout https://gist.github.com/javikin/ebf0dd43ee80f1be969d901ffe1bb302, I'm not sure if still works because is a 2 years implementation.

Comment: nice @JavierOlan to be so helpful after few years

Comment: I tried your code @JavierOlan but could not get it to work when the preview of the camera is stretched. Do you think this can be solved using other math? Please notice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480137/metadataoutputrectconvertedfromlayerrect-in-android